# Relationship between the incomplete gamma function of 2a and a

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables, gamma-function, density-function, gamma-distribution

If the gamma function is given by

$$\Gamma(\alpha) = \int_0^{+\infty}t^{\alpha-1}e^{-t}\text dt$$

and the lower incomplete gamma function by

$$\gamma(\alpha,x) = \int_{0}^{x}t^{\alpha-1}e^{-t}\text dt$$

Is it possible to derive $\gamma(2\alpha,x)$ from $\gamma(\alpha,x)$, $\Gamma(\alpha)$, and $\Gamma(2\alpha)$? The reason why I believe a relationship like that must hold is that, when [adding two random variables distributed according to a truncated $\Gamma(\alpha,\beta)$ distribution](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/236626/sum-of-truncated-gammas) with support on $[0,w)$

$$f(x;\alpha,\beta)=\mathbb{1}_{0\leq x < w}\frac{\beta^\alpha x^{\alpha-1} e^{-x\beta}}{\gamma(\alpha,w\beta)}$$

I get a term that goes like

$$\mathbb{1}_{0\leq x < w}\frac{\beta^{2\alpha} x^{2\alpha-1} e^{-x\beta}}{\gamma(\alpha,w\beta)^2} \frac{\Gamma(\alpha)^2}{\Gamma(2\alpha)}$$

which looks a *lot* like the truncated gamma function with parametre $2\alpha$

$$\mathbb{1}_{0\leq x < w}\frac{\beta^{2\alpha} x^{2\alpha-1} e^{-x\beta}}{\gamma(2\alpha,w\beta)}$$

Comment: If you meant $x$ is fixed then no, because $f_{X+Y}(x_0)$ ($X,Y$ independent) doesn't depend only on $f_X(x_0)$ and $f_Y(x_0)$ but on $f_X(x)$ and $f_Y(x_0-x)$ for every $x$

Comment: I don't understand how this relates to my question.

Comment: I explained why your argument "adding two random variables distributed according to a truncated Γ(α,β) distribution" is flawed : adding two (independent) r.v. means convoluting their pdf, and for this you need to know their whole pdf, not only their value at $x_0$

Comment: I didn't understand your explanation, then; could you elaborate on it?

Comment: Can you write the pdf of $X+Y$  in term of the pdf of $X$ and $Y$ (when $X,Y$ are independent) ?

Comment: Yes; it's written out in full in the link provided.

Comment: Then write it for $X,Y$ your incomplete gamma distributions.. What do you get ?

Comment: I get the thing from the link.

Answer (score 2):

Notice that

$$\gamma(s, x) + \Gamma(s, x) = \Gamma(s)$$

Now if $s = 2\alpha$...

Notice also that

$$\Gamma(2\alpha) = \frac{2^{2\alpha - 1}}{\sqrt{\pi}}\Gamma\left(\alpha + \frac{1}{2}\right)\Gamma(\alpha)$$

Comment: Finding $\gamma(2\alpha,x)$ from $\Gamma(2\alpha)$ and $\Gamma(2\alpha, x)$ is indeed straightforward but I don't have $\Gamma(2\alpha, x)$, I have instead $\Gamma(\alpha)$ and $\gamma(\alpha, x)$.

Comment: @PedroCarvalho Use the duplication formula for $\Gamma(s)$ (I'm going to edit the answer).

Comment: You might find this article useful, maybe. https://arxiv.org/pdf/0712.0292.pdf

Comment: The paper doesn't seem to address the incomplete function, nor does it seem possible to use the formulas you mentioned there to derive anything from the terms I do have there; am I missing something?

Comment: @PedroCarvalho Maybe I'm missing something but didn't you ask how is possible to fine $\gamma(2\alpha, x)$ from $\gamma(\alpha, x)$ et cetera.. Hence

$$\gamma(2\alpha, x) = \Gamma(2\alpha) - \Gamma(2\alpha, x)$$

Now you can use the formula for $\Gamma(2\alpha)$  I gave you.

It's a start! The problem is $\Gamma(2\alpha, x)$, which you can write through the Generalised Exponential Integral function:

$$\Gamma(2\alpha, x) = x^{2\alpha}\text{E}_{1-2\alpha}(x)$$

Comment: The problem there is that I have to subtract that value from somewhere not multiply. In the ideal world I'd get a duplication formula for $\gamma(\alpha,x)$ but it would seem one doesn't exist.

Comment: @PedroCarvalho Interesting! I will think about!!